# What is the correct syntax for getting timestamps before a certain time?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to return all the timestamps from a database as long as they are before 6 am on the day they were made. I tried to do this:

```
SELECT source_created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/PACIFIC' FROM time_entry
WHERE source_created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/PACIFIC' < '06:00:00'::time
```

but got this error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone < time without time zone
LINE 2: WHERE source_created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/PACIFIC' < '06:00:0...
```

I also tried `< '06:00:00'` and `TIME'06:00:00;` but got the same error. I'm new to SQL and the documentation has not been helpful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot compare a timestamp to a time. You need to cast the timestamp to time first:

```
WHERE (source_created_at AT TIME ZONE 'US/PACIFIC')::time < '06:00:00'::time
```

---

**Edit** from the comments

If you want all timestamps before tomorrow 6 AM in the same timezone:

```
WHERE source_created_at at time zone 'US/PACIFIC'
    < current_date at time zone 'US/PACIFIC' + interval '1 day 6 hour'
```

Comment: This worked but I actually made a mistake in my question. If I wanted the timestamps for times created before 6 am the NEXT day, how would I modify my query?

Comment: @arcadianrhythm: this is unclear. What do you call the *next* day?

Comment: so let's say a timestamp was made today, October 25th, at 12 pm. I'd want to retrieve that timestamp since it was made before 6 am tomorrow, October 26th. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK. You want tomorrow 6 AM in time zone US/PACIFIC, or in local time zone?

Comment: in the US/PACIFIC time zone